# How do I append the terminal output date on a text file. Specifically appending the date at the bottom of the file

Tags: shell, operating-system

With date > info.txt  I can append at the beginning, I want it to write at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

With > a given file is overwritten as output redirection start from the beginning of the file. >> will append redirection to the end of the file.

Taken from man bash:

Redirecting Output
Redirection of output causes the  file  whose  name  results  from  the
expansion of word to be opened for writing on file descriptor n, or the
standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not specified.  If the file
does  not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero
size.

```
   The general format for redirecting output is:

          [n]>word

   If the redirection operator is >, and the noclobber option to  the  set
   builtin  has  been enabled, the redirection will fail if the file whose
   name results from the expansion of word exists and is a  regular  file.
   If the redirection operator is >|, or the redirection operator is > and
   the noclobber option to the set builtin command is not enabled, the reâ
   direction is attempted even if the file named by word exists.
```

Appending Redirected Output
Redirection  of  output  in  this  fashion  causes  the file whose name
results from the expansion of word to be opened for appending  on  file
descriptor  n,  or  the standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not
specified.  If the file does not exist it is created.

```
   The general format for appending output is:

          [n]>>word
```